# It seems Protractor is ignored the promise of expect in it blocks

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, jasmine, protractor

The Protractor doesn't wait the complete load of the page. The `expect` is ignored.

I've tried to use `wait` with `ExpectedConditions` such as `visibilityOf` or `presenceOf`.

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  const page: Page = new Page();
  const ad: Ad = new Ad();

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const signIn = new SignIn();
    const dashboard = new Dashboard();
    const order = new Order();

    await new AppPage().navigateTo();
    await browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
    await page.navigateTo();
    await expect(await page.getH1Text()).toEqual('Sign In');
    await browser.refresh(); // Added due to http://git.io/v4gXM
    await expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('${BaseUrl}login');
    await signIn.form.loginForm.loginAsCustomer();
    await expect(await dashboard.isDisplayedUsername()).toBeTruthy();
    await expect(await dashboard.getUsername()).toBe('BB');
    await browser.refresh(); // Added due to http://git.io/v4gXM
    await expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('{BaseUrl}dashboard');

    await browser.get('{BaseUrl}order');

    const name: string = await order.getPageName();
    await expect(name).toBe('Orders');
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.dx-headers.dx-datagrid'))), 20000);
  });

  it('should select order', async () => {
    const grid: Grid = new Grid();
    const order: string = await grid.gridOrder.getAttributeOrderFromGrid('Test');
    await grid.gridOrder.selectOrderFromGrid('Test');
    await expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(order);
    await expect(await ad.getOrderNameLabel()).toBe('Test');
  });
});
```

**Error:**

```sh
Failed: Wow, you try to apply find() on empty Array Error: Wow, you try to apply find() on empty Array
```

There are no any issues if add `await browser.sleep(3000)`

**The issue is in the following part of the code:**

```js
const name: string = await order.getPageName();
await expect(name).toBe('Orders');
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.dx-headers.dx-datagrid'))), 20000);
```

Comment: What error or issue are you seeing.Also as an fyi `expects` are not promises themselves so do not require `awaits` but the contents do (as you are correctly doing already).

Comment: You need to add a proper wait function for waiting for page. In `angularjs` use `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` and for non-angular pages simply wait for an object to be present on page via `browser.wait()`

Comment: @DublinDev I've got the following error ```Failed: Wow, you try to apply find() on empty Array
Error: Wow, you try to apply find() on empty Array
``` if I add ```await browser.sleep(3000);``` it works fine

Comment: @SilvanBregy Yes, I've already added ```wait``` inside ```await expect(await ad.getOrderNameLabel()).toBe('Test');```.                                                           
 It looks like                             
```public async getOrderNameLabel(): Promise<string> {
    const page: Fragment = new Fragment($('h3[class="page-name"]'));
    await WaitConditions.visible(page);
    await page.waitForVisible();
    return await page.getFragmentText();
  }```